# Is it correct behaviour that an Area 51 ad isn't refreshed in more than a week?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

How often are the Area 51 ads refreshed?

If everything's going okay, it's more than a week, because the Espionage proposal has over 10 followers for more than a week now, but...

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Espionage]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/54104.png))</sub>

- If this is incorrect behaviour: please treat this as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
- If this is meant this way, please treat it as a [support](/questions/tagged/support) (I'd like to know the refresh interval) and a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) (I'd like to see it increased)

Comment: The other followers are simply too stealthy to show up in the count.

Comment: It takes a few days, but not more than a week. Also, this should be on A51-Meta

Comment: @AshRj that's good information. Do you have any reference or is this experience?

Comment: Experience/Observation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it *is* cached and won't update in real-time, but it turns out there was also a bug updating the cache... That's fixed now (try a hard refresh if you don't see it - your browser caches these too).

Comment: Thanks! Can something be said about the refresh interval?